# Beginner looking for resources for stepper motor programming

Tags: c, embedded, controls

I'm trying to teach myself to program stepper motors. I am a beginner at motor control, but I do have college level programming experience with GUI and embedded systems.

Can anybody lead me in the right direction as far as some good resources.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, this should get you started:

- [Microprocessor stepper motor programming](http://goo.gl/h5IUQ)